# Like Mac. Close Tap (lid) and active hybrid-suspend 14.04

Tags: laptop, suspend, hibernate, mate, lid

I would like to configure my OS, to Close the lid of the laptop, block the access and later of 10 or 20 minute active hybrid-suspend.
someone can help?..
I know to close the lid and active the hybrid-suspend, but I would like to add timer.

The hibernate is working correctly

Ubuntu mate 64bit 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this by configuring `logind.conf` - this will also override any of your user's power settings, and will work whether you are logged in or not (system-wide). You can configure it via running:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

You should like something like this:
[image: GNU nano 2.2.6 File: /etc/systemd/logind.conf]

Change the below lines to this:

```
HandleLidSwitch=lock
IdleAction=hybrid-sleep
IdleActionSec=1200
```

<sup>with no `#` at the beginning of any of the lines- a `#` at the beginning of the line means it is a comment and will be ignored and the defaults will be used</sup>

This should mean that when the lid is closed the computer locks; and when it is left idle (for 20 minutes (`20x60=1200` seconds) it will enter a hybrid-sleep state - the idle action will also take place with the lid *open*, and the configuration file may accept the time in minutes: `IdleActionSec=30min`.

Note that after making the changes you may need to restart `logind` or the system to see if the changes work.

Here is a quote from the [manual page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#HandlePowerKey=) - note other values like `lock`, `poweroff` etc can be used.

> ### HandlePowerKey=, HandleSuspendKey=, HandleHibernateKey=, HandleLidSwitch=
>
> Controls whether logind shall handle the system power and sleep keys and the lid switch to trigger actions such as system power-off or
>   suspend. Can be one of *"ignore"*, *"poweroff"*, *"reboot"*, *"halt"*,
>   *"kexec"*, *"suspend"*, *"hibernate"*, *"hybrid-sleep"* and *"lock"*. If
>   *"ignore"*, logind will never handle these keys. If *"lock"*, all running
>   sessions will be screen-locked; otherwise, the specified action will
>   be taken in the respective event. Only input devices with the
>   *"power-switch"* udev tag will be watched for key/lid switch events.
>   `HandlePowerKey=` defaults to *"poweroff"*. **`HandleSuspendKey=` and
>   `HandleLidSwitch=` defaults to *"suspend"***. `HandleHibernateKey=` defaults to
>   *"hibernate"*.
>
> ### IdleAction=
>
> Configures the action to take when the system is idle. Takes one of *"ignore", "poweroff", "reboot", "halt", "kexec", "suspend"*,
>   *"hibernate", "hybrid-sleep", and "lock"*. Defaults to *"ignore"*.
>
> Note that this requires that user sessions correctly report the idle status to the system. The system will execute the action after
>   all sessions report that they are idle, no idle inhibitor lock is
>   active, and subsequently, the time configured with `IdleActionSec=` (see
>   below) has expired.
>
> ### IdleActionSec=
>
> Configures the delay after which the action configured in `IdleAction=` (see above) is taken after the system is idle.

Comment: **+1**, let me try @Wilf

Comment: My idea is close lid and **with the lid closed, wait 20 minutes** and active hybrid-suspend